# Azure Service Bus Queue - auto delete messages

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

Is it possible to create a queue in Service Bus and specify that when a message is published it is automatically deleted?

Comment: Are referring to a TTL on messages that were not consumed on time? If not, please explain what do you mean.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your ask? Like Sean mentioned, do you mean a TTL on the message sent into a queue?

Comment: I have an existing Logic Apps that, in case of error, is publishing the message into a queue. The queue is then used by an error process to manage it and notify people if needed.
I need to add the exact same Logic Apps and deployed it in parallel in order to manage another system I'm connected with but in case of error I just want to ignore the error and not publish the message. But I want to avoid updating my code and I'm looking for a way to publish message in a queue where messages will just disapear.

Comment: Where did you publish the message? In the logic app or the code. And if in the logic app did you just not want to publish the message when occur error. Another question what do you mean a way to publish message in a queue where messages will just disappear.

Comment: The message is published from a Logic App with the Service Bus connector. The message is published in a queue.
What I mean: I want the Logic App to continue to publish the message in the queue but I just want messages to be removed from the queue automatically because no one will consume them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you want to send the message and want the message deleted automatically. Suppose what you want could be implemented with TTL.

When you use logic app to send message, there is an option **Time To Live** , check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#send-one-or-more-messages). The description is

> This is the duration, in ticks, that a message is valid. The duration starts from when the message is sent to the Service Bus.

[image]

Also you could set the queue TTL in the portal under your queue Properties.

[image]

Comment: Yes but - I'm not sure - messages are not removed from the queue even if they expired until someone read the queue. It means that I need to build a queue consumer just to put messages away from the queue (which is sometthing I can do for sure, thanks to a logic app for example).

Comment: @David GROSPELIER,I have a test it works, please check  [time to live](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/#send-one-or-more-messages) description, it's in ticks. Check my [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Jud.png) and [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7plm.png), I set with `1200000000` it will expire after 2 minutes and the servicebus explorer did show the right expire date. I receive message with peek mode and it will disappear at the right time.

Comment: @David GROSPELIER, any update on this issue, could you set the ttl now?

Comment: Yes: it works. Message disappear as soon as it expire but sometimes there is a small period of time between the expiration and the moment of it disappears.